# input index file not found

Tags: errors, indexing, input

I am using TeXnicCentre. After compiling, while I get an output pdf file, an error is found that says

> Could't find input index file `pathname` nor `pathname.idx`

I am afraid I cant pinpoint the error.
Please help.

Here are my (simplified) tex and bib files

```
%TeX file
\documentclass{article}
\author{Abhimanyu Arora}
\title{Experiments}
\maketitle
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
This is a simple trial file. For more details refer \cite{Arora}
\bibliography{ref}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}


%Bib file
@article{Arora,
  author = {Arora, Abhimanyu},
  year = {2011},
  title = {How to get unstuck},
  journal = {American Economic Review},
  volume = {87},
  number = {1},
  pages = {1--30},
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go into TeXnicCenters menu `Output->active output profile` (don't really know the english names) and disable the checkbox for using `makeindex`

Answer (score 10):

When I encountered this problem, Herbert's solution works if indeed you dont want to create an index. In the case that you do need to, and are trying to compile but get this error, make sure you have the code line `\makeindex` *in your preamble* so that you create the index file!
:)

Comment: This should be the answer. You are a saviour!! @Tino